# SwiftUI .onDisappear

Tags: swift, swiftui

For the application I am designing, I have a prominent header that we want to appear on our Homepage. I want it to disappear when I navigate into a child view, a dynamic view embedded within a custom SwiftUI element I created entitled a `CategoryRow`.

I've got it working, sort of, where the header disappears upon navigation into `NavigationLink` that I have embedded within the `CategoryRow`. Only problem is, the response time is a bit slow, and it seems as if the `onDisappear` event within the `NavigationLink` only fires sometimes. Here's a gif that demonstrates the exact behavior I am facing:

[image: broken]

Here's some of the relevant code I have within my parent view, which I have entitled `FeedView`:

```
@State private var showHeader = true // showHeader will be a state variable passed between the parent and child in order to show/hide the header

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        if showHeader { // update and show/hide the header embedded in the HStack on state change
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                // header
            }
        }

        NavigationView {
            List(categories.keys.sorted(), id: \String.self) {
                // we pass the state variable over to the CategoryRow class to be used in appear/disappear
                key in CategoryRow(nameOfCategory: "\(key)".uppercased(), posts: self.posts[key]!, showHeader: self.$showHeader)
            }
        }
```

(Child View; a CategoryRow element):

```
@Binding var showHeader: Bool // bind the passed in showHeader variable so we can pass it back to the parent when updates need to happen

// ...

NavigationLink(destination: ExpandMediaView(post: post)
    .onAppear { self.showHeader = false } // after testing, this onAppear ALWAYS manages to fire
    .onDisappear { self.showHeader = true } // why does this only fire sometimes? 
)
```

The code only hits the `.onDisappear` portion of the NavigationLink sometimes, which means sometimes the header reappears on the parent class, and sometimes it doesn't. On top of this, the show/hiding of it is about a millisecond behind the page navigation. Has anyone worked through an issue like this before?

Comment: have you tried same on device?

Comment: Not yet. Do you think this is just a bug with Simulator/Xcode?

Comment: Probably. Number of issues are occurring in a similar way which occur on simulator only but not on device.

Comment: I'll try out the code on a physical device and see how that reacts tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't able to even run the application on my device. Anytime I tried to move into the screen where this issue is occurring, Xcode would just hit me with a `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

Comment: Have you try add .onAppear { self.showHeader = true} // after testing, this onAppear ALWAYS manages to fire
    .onDisappear { self.showHeader = false} in your parent View

Comment: Doesn't this code need to be attached to the `NavigationLink`? I create that in the child view; which is why I have been attaching this code there this whole time.